# I need my Process entry criteria to look at the value of a currency formula field

Tags: formula, process-builder

This is a bit complex-but I'll try to simplify.

## STATEMENT

"Transaction" object has a Custom Currency Formula Field "Amount Outstanding"
Child object "Payment" has a Status pick list field.

I want my Process on the Payment object to run when the following is true.

**Payment.Status = X
AND
Transaction.Amount_Outstanding > 0**

If that fires, then do a field update.

This of course fails, because you can't use a Formula field as the criteria for a process unless it displays True or False.

## SO HOW DO I SOLVE THIS?

The problem of course is that currency formula field.

It is a IF Statement so it either displays 0 or it displays the difference between two standard currency fields.

**(TotalAmount- TotalRefundAmount) - PaymentAmount  +  OverPaymentAmount )**

(Those Amount fields are a mixture of Currency, Roll-Up and Formula fields)
Is there an easier way to accomplish this OTHER than doing a new Workflow/Process on the Transaction object to do a field update on a new field with the above formula for the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the entry criteria for a Process Builder to be for [Payment].Status = X and [Payment].Transaction.Amount_Outstanding > 0?

If that is the case, why don't you just use "formula evaluates to true" for the criteria for the PB? That should allow you to reference the currency field from the Transaction.

Another option would be to create a formula on the Payment object that checks if the Transaction.Amount_Outstanding > 0 and have the formula output type be a checkbox, and use that as the criteria (if you need a true/false value).

Hopefully, I did understand you correctly and this works for you.

Comment: *Another option would be to create a formula on the Payment object that checks if the Transaction.Amount_Outstanding > 0 and have the formula output type be a checkbox, and use that as the criteria (if you need a true/false value).*  THIS WORKS!!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can mark it as the best answer then so that anyone who finds this question in the future knows that the answer is correct.